# Writing a list comprehension with if else statement

Tags: python, pandas, list-comprehension

I'm trying to write a list comprehension where, if the value is an integer, it will multiply by 1,000,000 but if it's not an integer the value will be 'np.NaN'.

Here's my code:

```
energy['Energy Supply'] = [n*1000000 if isinstance(n,int) == True else n == 'np.Nan' for n in energy['Energy Supply']]
```

Data frame returned showing the ['Energy Supply'] column with False where there was not an integer.

I then tried writing another list comprehension to fix the issue:

```
energy['Energy Supply'] = [n.replace(to_replace='False',value='np.Nan') for n in energy['Energy Supply']]
```

I got this error:

> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>         5         energy['Energy Supply'] = [n.replace(to_replace='False',value='np.Nan') for n in energy['Energy
>   Supply']]
>         6         return energy
>   ----> 7 answer_one()
>
> in answer_one()
>         3         energy.columns = ['Country', 'Energy Supply', 'Energy Supply per Capita', '% Renewable']
>         4         energy['Energy Supply'] = [n*1000000 if isinstance(n,int) == True else n == str('np.nan') for n in
>   energy['Energy Supply']]
>   ----> 5         energy['Energy Supply'] = [n.replace(to_replace='False',value='np.Nan') for n in energy['Energy
>   Supply']]
>         6         return energy
>         7 answer_one()
>
> in (.0)
>         3         energy.columns = ['Country', 'Energy Supply', 'Energy Supply per Capita', '% Renewable']
>         4         energy['Energy Supply'] = [n*1000000 if isinstance(n,int) == True else n == str('np.nan') for n in
>   energy['Energy Supply']]
>   ----> 5         energy['Energy Supply'] = [n.replace(to_replace='False',value='np.Nan') for n in energy['Energy
>   Supply']]
>         6         return energy
>         7 answer_one()
>
> AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'replace'

Thanks in advance, stack overflow community.

Comment: Please put your code in code blocks.

Comment: Add sample data and expected output in your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you don't need to do equality check `n == np.nan`, but you have to initialize as `n = np.nan`. Since initialization in list comprehension does not require =, it can be done as `energy['Energy Supply'] = [n * 1000000 if isinstance(n, int) == True else np.nan for n in energy['Energy Supply']]`. This will solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

your first code is not working properly b/c you are using `==` after else

```
energy['Energy Supply'] = [n*1000000 if isinstance(n,int) == True else 'np.Nan' for n in energy['Energy Supply']]
```

To get rid of `False` you can use mapping

```
d={False:np.nan}
energy['Energy Supply']=energy['Energy Supply'].map(d)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand you correctly, but if so - does this work?

```
energy['Energy Supply'] = [n*1000000 if isinstance(n,int) == True else 'np.Nan' for n in energy['Energy Supply']]
```